# Pace.js takes longer to load on FireFox

Tags: html, pace.js

I'm using pace.js on my website. When I open a website in Firefox, progress reaches 99% on and really slows down, increasing by a tiny amount. Eventually, after several seconds, it reaches 100% and finally loads.

On Chrome everything works fine.

Comment: You need to be specific. There could be hundreds of  reasons that could be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. For some reason, event lag checks had been taking a lot of time. When I set `"eventLag": false` everything started working properly